# pycharm and tensorflow-gpu; DLL not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get a github repository to work on my pc. This repository is based on tensorflow-gpu. Currently, when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/audio/deep-voice-conversion-master/deep-voice-conversion-master/convert.py", line 9, in <module>
    from models import Net2
  File "D:\audio\deep-voice-conversion-master\deep-voice-conversion-master\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "D:\audio\deep-voice-conversion-master\deep-voice-conversion-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\audio\deep-voice-conversion-master\deep-voice-conversion-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "D:\audio\deep-voice-conversion-master\deep-voice-conversion-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "D:\audio\deep-voice-conversion-master\deep-voice-conversion-master\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protoWbuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found.
```

I am using pycharm on windows 10, with python 3.6.

I tried to follow [these steps](http://blog.nitishmutha.com/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html), but it seems outdated and I did not get it to work. I also prefer not to use anaconda, as this is a huge package and I only want to get this repository to work. So far, I have done the following:

- I have installed all required packages (including the tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu packages) via pip.
- I also downloaded CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN.
- I have copied the files from cuDNN's  bin, include and lib folders into the corresponding folders from CUDA.
- I added the path to the cuda folder to the environment PATH from windows
- I added the CUDA and cuDNN folder paths to the Content root folders of the project structure in pycharm (probably not helpful but someone somewhere suggested it)

I am new to tensorflow and I have no Idea what I have to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like some issue with protobuf. This might help you https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf seems to be a conda package. Try installing it with

```
conda install protobuf
```

Or

```
pip install protobuf
```

Comment: I got it to work! I downgraded protobuf from 3.6.1 to 3.6.0, and that worked